# 'generator' object has no attribute error in accessing the tree levels in python

Tags: python, nltk

This is my code:

```
from nltk import load_parser

cp = load_parser('grammars/book_grammars/sql0.fcfg')
query = 'What cities are located in China'
trees = cp.parse(query.split())
answer = trees[0].node['sem']
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Why it is giving such error, what is the solution of it?

Comment: Looks like `cp.parse` is a generator. If you only need the first value, use `next(trees)`, otherwise convert it to list or other sequence.

Comment: `trees = list(cp.parse(query.split()))`

Comment: But it is giving S[SEM=(SELECT, City FROM city_table, WHERE, , , Country="china")] I want just SELECT, City FROM city_table, WHERE, , , Country="china"

Comment: Any solution here!